# XML to JSON and vice versa conversion with same results

Tags: java, arrays, json, xml, type-conversion

My JavaScript  requires some data in JSON format. However I'm going to maintain the same data in server-side in XML format. Therefore I use a Jackson/ org.json libraries to convert XML into JSON.

However I have issues with getting the JSON format which I wan't from XML.

1. JSON required for me is (i.e. arrays)

   {
   "div" : [
       "some text", 
       { "p": "some text"}, 
       "some text again"
   ]
   }

First I converted this into XML and then converted that XML to JSON using the same library, but couldn't get the JSON format which I wanted. How can I represent this JSON in XML so that I can convert and get the same JSON format.

2. Also I need some JSONs with '[]' in keys/names.

   {
     "div[name=x]" : { ... }
   }

The above kind of JSONs also resulting in the same issue.

Comment: *Write* some code that *walks* the XML DOM (or the *original tree data*) and creates the appropriate *custom* JSON structure (eg. JSONArray, JSONObject) per the specific rules desired.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a generic solution - because I will have different xmls. The requirement here however is to represent a  jason array and keys with square brackets in xml - and to convert them as is into json

Comment: That **is** a *generic solution* where *you* define the mapping using whatever rules are appropriate. The standard XML to JSON (or vice versa) conversion does the same kind of structure walk - only using it's own (and not the desired) rules.